# On click, compare id's of selected checkboxes to list hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a list of checkboxes, that change on container li click. 
Here is one for example, and the rest of them are the same (except for a few id's and classes , that dynamically change like #lips here)

```
<li class="lifilter">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="lips" checked="checked">
  <label for="Lips..." class="lips">
    <a href="lips">Lips</a>
  </label>
</li>
```

on click, .filtercheck gets class of .checkchecked (if it helps)

there is also a list of links

```
<div class="collectionurls"> 
  <a class="colurls colurl1" href="/collections/lips"></a>     
  <a class="colurls colurl2" href="/collections/face-lips"></a>     
  <a class="colurls colurl3" href="/collections/face-cheeks"></a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to compare checkbox id, when .lifilter is clicked to that list of urls, pick one that has all the checked id's, add it to current domain, and redirect page there.

For example: Let's say, #face is already checked, site visitor clicks on #lips. Script checks .colurls for face and lips. In our case, finds .colurl2, gets its href, adds to curdomain, and redirects page to domain.com/collections/face-leeps

There is a pretty long script of forming these id's and classes, but i got really stuck here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var curdomain = document.domain;
//id's and classes forming code  
  $('.lifilter').click(function(){
          //compare ids to hrefs
  var addurl = // that class attr('href')
  var curdomain = curdomain + addurl;
  window.location = curdomain;
  });
});
```

I'm pretty new to js, and have no clue where to go from here. And there is most likely a syntax error where i'm combining vars.

Help a noob out plz

Comment: Maybe try: `var addurl = this.href;`?

Comment: there may be quite a few classes that could be applied to url, so no clue what to do with those

Comment: At what point are you stuck, exactly one.

Comment: the whole idea of matching multiple checked ids to list of hrefs. i can find match one, but how do i match unlimited number of checked?

Comment: Is there a certain order? For instance, when both `face` and `lips` are checked, does the URL have to be `/collections/face-lips` or can it be `/collections/lips-face`?

Comment: those may vary in order

Comment: Take a global array having the number of elements equal in number of LIs. When each checkbox is clicked, call a function that gets the id of clicked checkbox/LI then set a 0/1 in the array with that respective array index you choose to the checkbox's ID
AND each time at end of the function, iterate the array and get the records value on each index to check which ones are checked and which ones are'nt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a strange way to do the navigation, but I would do this like so:

1. Build an array of [jQuery attribute contains selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/), using all the checked checkboxes and [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. Join those selectors together and apply the resulting [multiple attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)
3. Check how many results you get. Once you have narrowed-down to one result, you have enough information to redirect.

There's a running snippet below. It doesn't actually redirect, but shows the redirect location, or the number of possible results.

```js
$(".filtercheck").on("click", function() {
  
  //build an array of jQuery contains selectors
  var selected = $(".filtercheck:checked").get().map(function(item) {
    return '[href*="' + item.id + '"]';
  });
  
  //join the selectors into a continuous string
  var selector = selected.join('');
  
  //run the jQuery selectors
  var result = $(".collectionurls " + selector);
  
  //if there is one result you can successfully navigate
  if (result.length === 1) {
    var href = result.attr("href");
    $("#result").val(href);
    //window.location = href; //uncomment to redirect
  }
  else {
    $("#result").val(result.length + " results");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="lifilter">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="face" checked>
  <label for="face" class="face">
    Face
  </label>
</li>
<li class="lifilter">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="lips">
  <label for="lips" class="lips">
    Lips
  </label>
</li>
<li class="lifilter">
  <input type="checkbox" class="filtercheck" id="cheeks">
  <label for="cheeks" class="cheeks">
    Cheeks
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="collectionurls"> 
  <a class="colurls colurl1" href="/collections/lips"></a>     
  <a class="colurls colurl2" href="/collections/face-lips"></a>     
  <a class="colurls colurl3" href="/collections/face-cheeks"></a>
</div>
<input id="result" />
```

Comment: for some reason doesn't really work on my site, but snippet obviously works. Let me dig into it for a few mins

Comment: What about it isn't working? Are you getting too many results, no results, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm gathering, you'll need to go through the checked checkboxes on your page and concatenate them together. The easiest way may be with [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map). You mentioned that the checked checkboxes get the class `checkchecked`, so:

```
var url = '/collections/' + $('.checkchecked').map(function (index, element) {
    return this.id;
}).join('-');
```

However, the order of the items in the URL will depend on the order in the document. For instance, if the `lips` checkbox comes before the `face` checkbox in document order, the `url` will be `'/collections/face-lips'`, but if the opposite is true, it will be `'/collections/lips-face'`.

If there needs to be a defined order, sort the array returned by `map`:

```
var parts = $('.checkchecked').map(function (index, element) {
    return this.id;
}).sort(); // This will sort them alphabetically

var url = '/collections/' + parts.join('-');
```

If you have a preset order, store that order in a separate array:

```
var order = [ 'face', 'cheeks', 'lips' ];
var parts = $('.checkchecked').map(function (index, element) {
    return this.id;
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return order.indexOf(a) - order.indexOf(b);
}); // This will sort by separate "order"

var url = '/collections/' + parts.join('-');
```

Comment: Do you think there is any way to make it not depend on order.

Comment: You could sort the array returned by `map`. I'll update my question.

Comment: the thing is that the order can be quite chaotic.

Comment: You mean the order in the URL? That sounds odd. You could also just create a hash of all possible permutations along with their canonical order. E.g., `{ "face-lips": "face-lips", "lips-face": "face-lips", "face-cheeks": "face-cheeks", "cheeks-face": "face-cheeks", etc...}` then just do a lookup...